# flaskでpostメソッドを実施すると外部キー制約周りでエラーが発生する

Tags: mysql, api, flask

flaskでAPIを作成しており、POSTメソッドを実装してみたところ、下記のようなエラーが発生しましたが、解決できず困っています。

- エラー内容

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`page`, CONSTRAINT `page_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`belong_id`) REFERENCES `belong` (`id`))') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO page (id, title, belong_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: (0, 'test', '', datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2, 6, 16, 56, 752822), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2, 6, 16, 56, 752822))] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019 06:16:56] "POST /pages?title=test HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

- flask POSTメソッド実装部分

```
@app.route('/pages',methods=['POST'])
def post_page():
    title = request.args.get('title','')
    belong_id = request.args.get('belong_id','')
    page_repository = PageRepository(access_point)
    page = page_repository.post(title,belong_id)
```

- 実行内容

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://0.0.0.0:8080/pages?belong_id=1&title=test
```

- o/rマッパー部分抜粋

```
class Relation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'relation'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    code_link = Column('code_link', Text)
    memo = Column('memo', Text)

class Belong(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'belong'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    relation_order = Column('relation_order', Integer, ForeignKey('relation.id', onupdate="CASCASE", ondelete="CASCASE"))
    page = relationship('Page')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

class Page(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'page'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String(200))
    belong_id = Column('belong_id', Integer, ForeignKey('belong.id', onupdate="CASCASE", ondelete="CASCASE"))
    created_at = Column(DateTime)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime)
```

relationテーブル、belongテーブルにはそれぞれ1レコード（id=1）データがそれぞれ既に入っています。
また、最初に入れていたデータがおかしいのかと思い、一度テーブルを削除、作り直しをしてデータを入れ直してもみましたが、同じエラーが発生しています。

恐れ入りますが何かご教授いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

エラー内容を見る限り、以下のクエリが発行されています。

```sql
INSERT INTO page (
    id, 
    title, 
    belong_id, 
    created_at, 
    updated_at
) 
VALUES (
    0, 
    'test', 
    '',        # ここが空
    '2019 01/02 ...',
    '2019 01/02 ...'
);
```

`belong_to` の値が空でMySQLの外部キー制約に反するためにINSERTができないのだと思われます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！確かにbelong_idが空になっていることが怪しいと思っており、コード側に問題があると思っていたのですが、POSTの仕方を見直してみたところ、http://0.0.0.0:8080/pages?belong_id=1\&title=test ここの&をエスケープしてあげることで無事POSTができました！ありがとうございました。

Comment: なるほど、`curl`のURL指定の仕方に問題があったのですね！ だとすれば、URLの部分をquotingしてやってもいけるのではないでしょうか？ 例えば `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/pages?belong_id=1&title=test'` てな具合ですね。

Comment: [ここ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261467/command-line-curl-with-quote-wrapped-url-works-php-curl-does-not)も参考になりそうです

Comment: ありがとうございます！！なるほど・・！早速試してみたところ、""で囲う方法でも上手く行きました！！感謝ですm(__)m